Uneven current sharing between four parallel cables
We are performing testing of an induction furnace where the power is supplied through diode based rectifier - half bridge inverter setup to the tank circuit by means of two sets of four 2 feet long 120 mm2 copper cables (phase & neutral) parallel connected between inverter IGBT and the melting coil. The operating frequency of the furnace is 7 kHz at 1000 V and 400 amps.
But measuring the current through the cable through a Rogowski shows uneven distribution of current through the cables. One cable is carrying higher current than others, two cables are carrying almost similar amount of current and the last one is carrying much lower current. I tried following remedies:

Checked for the loose connections, none found.
Flattened the lug surfaces for even surface contact, didn't help much.
Checked the resistance of the cables using LCR, all showed same resistance.


do NOT write information in comments ... edit the question instead

Can you add a schematic with the length of the wires and "disposition" ?

induction furnace … inverter What frequency & waveform, and what are the dimensions & arrangement of the conductors?

What are you using to measure resistance? If the resistance were equal, the current would be equal. You must use a DLRO made for switch gear using a 100amp or higher current source. To solve the problem, start with the conductor taking the least amount of current.

@Dereck Proximity effects can make the AC resistance different at higher frequencies even if the DC resistance is the same.  So, routing can make a difference, but I wouldn't expect a big difference in this case based on how it's described.  Not enough information to be sure though.

@Dereck I used lcr meter.

@JohnD I thought proximity effect might be the cause. So how physically far should cables be arranged to reduce the effect? The inverter is half bridged operating at 7kHz freq, 1000V, 400Amps

"Checked the resistance of the cables using lcr, all showed same resistance." An LRC meter cannopt measure the micro-ohm resistance of those cables. You meed a microOhmmeter that uses a Kelvin connection.

Please show how the cables are arranged relative to each other: at the source terminals, at the load, and typically along the length of the route.

You are probably running in to proximity effects, that is, adjacent conductors will cause an uneven current density within the cross section of the conductor. "Soft Ferrites", by E.C. Snelling has a good write up on proximity effect.
Just for fun, I cobbled up a test setup with two pairs of #25 AWG (0.455 mm diameter) conductors about 610 mm (2 feet) long. Each wire was separated by about 11.7 mm as shown in the upper configuration in the diagram. You didn't supply a diagram showing the configuration of the conductors, so the upper diagram is a guess as to what your configuration is.

For the upper configuration in the diagram, measuring the current in each wire with an oscilloscope clamp-on current probe at 2 MHz, the outer wires (conductors 1 & 4) carried 8.1 mA, the inner wires (conductors 2 & 3) carried 11.1 mA. 
The series components, as measured by the impedance analyzer at 2 MHz: L = 741 nH, R = 272 mohm.
Twisting the pairs together, as shown in the lower diagram, the current measured in each wire was 9.2 mA. The pairs were separated by approximately 11.7 mm.
The series components, as measured by the impedance analyzer at 2 MHz: L = 906 nH, R = 312 mohm.
Comments about the setup:

The mechanical setup is unstable. Wire separation was approximate as the separation varied along the length since solid wire was used.
Twisting of the wires wasn't carefully controlled (pitch and gaps between conductors).
The current probe changes the impedance of the wire.
2 MHz was chosen since proximity, and possibly skin effects started to show up at 1 MHz.

Try the second configuration and see if that helps balance the current flow.

It's normal that L is higher (effectively, the average distance between conductors is larger; it might also be differences in setup, hard to tell without fixturing of course), but interesting that R is higher (if only minorly). Presumably, OP is using litz cables, which will share current better (both within and between) if the inductance is equalized. (And if not, that would be important information to include!)

A standard solution for this (and I seriously wonder why it wasn't designed that way in the first place, or suggested by the induction heater manufacturer, etc.) is to use kickless cables.  Example from Flex Cable.  At [prior employer], we used these (think it was even same brand..) for extending the connection from power supply / heat station* and work coil, on the occasion where it couldn't be positioned better.
*Typically, induction heating supplies include a resonant capacitor, transformer, or both, between inverter and work coil.  This can be positioned to optimize flexibility and economy, as far as range of positioning for the coil.
Kickless cables are constructed of myriad twisted pairs, in parallel.  This keeps the currents equal and opposite, balanced within the build of the cable itself, and keeps mechanical forces down by pairing up small wires -- hence the term "kickless".
They're often used in powerful applications where high currents would otherwise cause the cables to, well, "kick" around, such as arc furnaces, spot welders, and pulsed power applications; perhaps the most notable example is the US Navy's railgun development program, which used an array of kickless cables to join the many capacitors to the gun itself.
Being built of smaller wires, they tend to share current well internally; otherwise, litz cables are required, which also drop more voltage due to inductance.
Like litz cable, kickless cables are excellent for high frequency use, particularly for induction heating where the stray inductance of long cables can reduce tuning range of the power supply.

When you have a bundle of wires the ones nearer the surface of the bundle will carry more current due to an electromagnetic coupling effect akin to the skin effect in a solid conductor. The way this is solved is to braid the wires so that each wire spends some time on the outside of the bundle. The resulting wire bundle is call Litz wire. You can get an eyeful of info by using wikipedia.
